# Question about webservices and apple acceptance

Tags: iphone

I have used web services to transfer money...

Actually my server handles all requests and sends data to main server...

will apple accept my application..??

Comment: Go to next page and open paypal page on safari for payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Suarabh G, that's false information. This is what it says in the App Store Review Guidelines:

Purchasing and currencies

11.1
Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

11.2
Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected

11.3
Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected

11.4
Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume those credits within the application

11.5
Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies that expire will be rejected

11.6
Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 30 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS devices

11.7
Apps that use IAP to purchase items must assign the correct Purchasability type

11.8
Apps that use IAP to purchase access to built-in capabilities provided by iOS, such as the camera or the gyroscope, will be rejected

11.9
Apps containing "rental" content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected

11.10
Insurance applications must be free, in legal-compliance in the regions distributed, and cannot use IAP

As for your question, Saawan, There's no way for us to know if Apple will accept your app or not. If your app is an app that transfers money using a web service, it depends on what the money is being transferred for. You can read the guidelines and hopefully you can find your answer.

Comment: thanks bro.  i have read those documents of apple..before putting this question..but was not cleared...so i wanted some experience of any programmer...but thanks for ans...and +1 for ans...thanks....

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't send the user outside the Apple purchase system. Use only the Apple payment system for that.